# Rails minitest returning "NoMethodError: undefined method `make_response!'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a couple tests that run fine independently

```
rails t test/controllers/briefs_controller_test.rb
Running via Spring preloader in process 24174
Run options: --seed 46330

# Running:

.................................

Finished in 9.219203s, 3.5795 runs/s, 3.9049 assertions/s.
33 runs, 36 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

But all together they produce

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 24023
Run options: --seed 35139

# Running:

..............................................................................................E

Error:
BriefsControllerTest#test_should_get_project_brief_by_admin:
NoMethodError: undefined method `make_response!' for ProjectsController:Class
    test/controllers/briefs_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:BriefsControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/briefs_controller_test.rb:7

.....E

Error:
BriefsControllerTest#test_should_get_project_brief_by_brand:
NoMethodError: undefined method `make_response!' for ProjectsController:Class
    test/controllers/briefs_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:BriefsControllerTest>'
```

I was suspecting fixtures at first but only controllers test with `get` or `post` with `project` routes are crashing.

```
require 'test_helper'

class BriefsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  include I18n::Alchemy

  test "should get project brief by admin" do
    sign_in users(:admin)
    get project_brief_url(projects(:project_two).id)
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get project brief by brand" do
    sign_in users(:brand)
    get project_brief_url(projects(:project_one).id)
    assert_response :success
  end

[end of test file removed for clarity ]
```

Any ideas ?

This only happens on routes based on `projects` calls on other routes are fine.

Comment: I think we need to see the `ProjectsController:Class` to understand this `make_response!` method that's breaking . My first assumption is that ProjectsController is not inheriting from ApplicationController. `class ProjectsController < ApplicationController` should be in the ProjectsController file

Comment: I found it, actually two different test files had the same class name, one should have been namespaced

Comment: Oddly, it had nothing to do with this test class...